# For access violation exceptions, should we blame the author?

Tags: c++, exception, native, access-violation

I am mostly programming managed code with C#. In the managed world, causing  a null reference exception is a big no no even if you catch them, and it's almost always the author's fault except thread safety misuses. Can we also conclude the same with native code as well? I mean if  a library causes access violation as first chance exception and even if this exception is handled by the library, can we say it's  a bug in the library?

Comment: No.  It could possibly be how the library is being used. Impossible to tell w/o the actual code.

Comment: It depends; did your code violate the libraries calling contract?

Comment: @RichardCritten that's my point i believe library author should validate the incoming data

Comment: @OnurGumus That's opinion based and off topic for SO.  For example the standard library has a contract (the standard) however it does not validate what you pass into it (only pay for what you need).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In native C++ code, "access violation errors" or "null reference errors" or the like are **not** exceptions at all. They're Undefined Behavior. The blame for that is squarely on the head of the responsible coder.

This *might* be the coder passing nonsense to the library. But that's no different from C# - the mantra "garbage in, garbage out" is quite universal.

Comment: I'd disagree.At least for C# regardless the input, you should never ever cause a null reference exception. That is by simply not trusting the input.

Comment: @OnurGumus: In C++ and C# alike, there is a limit to how deep you can check that. Trivially, if you get a non-null `Object` but `Object.Foo()` causes a null reference exception due to some private field, you can't blame the library author. Blame the person who created that flawed Object. For a more realistic example, consider a graph algorithm that works only on acyclic graphs - it may very well cause a null reference exception when it does encounter a cycle. But detecting a cycle is very expensive.

Comment: Also, in C++ you simply cannot handle an access violation. There's no way to check in advance if an address is valid (besides NULL), and handling the resulting problem is both platform dependent and unsafe anyway - if you get an access violation you may have already broken up your data structures (or even the stack) beyond salvation. Try to do the minimum amount of logging if you really must and let it crash.

Comment: @MSalters, Of course, but the access violation will not originate from the library in this case but from object.foo. i am referring to the case the call stack of exception points to the library at the time of exception.